UnauthorizedAccessException using Azure Files when storage account network access enabled for selected networks only
My website (ASP.NET Core, Windows, hosted in Azure app service using IIS) uses the Azure Files feature of my Azure Storage Account to read and write files and directories. It does this using the normal System.IO methods File.Open, etc.
This all works fine as long "Public network access" on the Networking page of the storage account is set to "Enabled from all networks".
However, I have now locked this down using a virtual network, so only my app service can talk to the storage account. Also created a managed identity for the app service and gave that identity the RBAC roles

"Storage Account Contributor"
"Storage File Data Privileged Contributor"
"Storage Blob Data Contributor"
"Storage File Data SMB Share Contributor"
"Reader and Data Access"

on the storage account.
As soon as I set "Public network access" on the Networking page of the storage account to "Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses", attempts to write a file now lead to an exception
UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '\\mystorage.file.core.windows.net\mydirectory\mfile.txt' is denied.

However, writing to a blob works fine. So the app service does reach the storage account.
What do I need to do to access my files with the storage account only accessible from the app service? I would much prefer to continue using the System.IO methods so I don't have to modify the application.

Can you please share the configuration of Storage in App Service?

You can enable a service endpoint for Azure Storage within the virtual network. The service endpoint routes traffic from the virtual network through an optimal path to the Azure Storage service. The identities of the subnet and the virtual network are also transmitted with each request. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal#grant-access-from-a-virtual-network

The Storage Account Contributor is not sufficient to access the fileshare you may assign the Storage File Data SMB Share Contributor to allow for read, write, and delete access on files and directories in Azure file shares. For more details, follow the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-identity-assign-share-level-permissions?tabs=azure-portal#azure-rbac-roles-for-azure-files6g

In your case, the ability to access the blob indicates that there is no problem with the network configuration.Assign the role and confirm it.

@VenkatV I've added "Storage File Data SMB Share Contributor" to the managed identity for the storage account. Same result, still getting the exception. Updated the question.

Also kindly check the Azure Fileshare authentication method; it should be Microsoft Entra user account if you are using the RBAC method. , if still having an issue, mount the Azure fileshare in the app service.

I hope this helps to resolve the problem.

To enable private access, you need to use Azure Private Endpoint.
In your case, you need to create one private endpoint per sub-resource and so one for blob access and another one for file share access.
If you use Terraform :
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "blob" {
  name                = "pe-stxxxx-blob"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.example.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "example-privateserviceconnection"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
    subresource_names              = ["blob"] <------
    is_manual_connection           = false
  }

  private_dns_zone_group {
    name                 = "example-dns-zone-group"
    private_dns_zone_ids = [azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.id]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "file" {
  name                = "pe-stxxxx-file"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.example.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "example-privateserviceconnection"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
    subresource_names              = ["file"] <------
    is_manual_connection           = false
  }

  private_dns_zone_group {
    name                 = "example-dns-zone-group"
    private_dns_zone_ids = [azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.id]
  }
}

References :

Azure Private Link resources: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-overview#private-link-resource
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-private-endpoints?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json#creating-a-private-endpoint


I'm not familiar with Terraform. I've been setting up the subnets via the portal where I didn't see an option to create sub-resource end points. Could you please tell me how to implement your suggestion via the portal?


UnauthorizedAccessException using Azure Files when storage account network access enabled for selected networks only

The error you encountered is due to a permission issue. If you can access the blob from an app service, there is no issue with the network configuration.
If you are trying to access the File Share data from the app service using the RBAC method, please configure the authentication method for the Microsoft Entra user account in Azure File Share.

If you are using the App Service system-managed identity to access the Azure File Share, make sure to assign the Storage File Data Privileged Contributor role to the app identity. For more details, follow this link.
Ensure that you use the identity-based authentication method in your code, rather than a SAS token or access keys.
In my case, I enabled identity for the App Service and mounted the Azure File Share on the App Service.

After enabling the identity and logging in with the App Service identity, try accessing the Azure File Share data, as it should work as expected.

Storage account firewall setting

App service network setting


I added "Storage File Data Privileged Contributor" RBAC role for the managed identity on the storage account. That didn't help, still getting the same exception. Question updated.

Okay, have you mounted the fileshare in appservice? If not, mount it and navigate to console or Adancetools to see if it is available using df -h command.If available, navigate to that path and try to open the files with the cat command.

Make sure the authentication method in fileshare is Entrant AD and then login with your app service identity in the console to see if you can access the fileshare data.
